# Wysiwyg Permissions for Anonymous Users

Tags: wysiwyg

I've installed WYSIWYG for my site editors, but it's also showing up in the comments field box. I don't want my anonymous users to be able to leave comments with the WYSIWYG (but I do want them to comment, with restrictions of course).

I tried looking in People > Permissions and found nothing. I looked through the settings also in Config > WYSIWYG and finally Modules > WYSIWYG.

Anyone know of a way to edit the WYSIWYG permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sage, edit the content type, go on the COMMENTS FIELDS tab, then click on edit on comment_body. 
Make sure you set 'Text processing'  to PLAIN TEXT